# How can I display email formatted as "FirstName LastName <FirstNameLastName@domain.com>" in HTML?

Tags: html, coldfusion

I am trying to display an email formatted as `"FirstName LastName <FirstNameLastName@domain.com>"` in HTML, and it is only displaying "FirstName LastName".

Pseudo-code:

```
<cfset LOCAL.From = "FirstName LastName <FirstNameLastName@domain.com>" />
<cfoutput>#Local.From#</cfoutput>
```

I know I can replace the less-than and greater-than signs with `lt;` and `gt;`, but I'm looking for a better way than `Replace(Replace(LOCAL.Form, "<", ";lt;"), ">", "&gt;")`.

I'm not very good with Regular Expressions, if that's the way to go, so show me a good RegEx for this, if you'd like.

Or, if this can be done simply with some ColdFusion function, that's great too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for HTML encoding, rather than string replacement. Use [HtmlEditFormat](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_h-im_04.html).

Possibly related: [How to encode HTML form in coldfusion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340968/how-to-encode-html-form-in-coldfusion)

Comment: Great. I knew that! The function just slipped my mind. Thanks.

Comment: Accepted (SO wouldn't let me accept as quick as I'd have liked!)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are getting the FirstName and LastName variables from somewhere, you need to specify them as output.  The way you've coded it, the string would always be the same and not dynamic.

```
<cfset FirstName = "John">
<cfset LastName = "Doe">
<cfset LOCAL.From = "#FirstName# #LastName# <#FirstName##LastName#@domain.com>" />
<cfoutput>#HTMLEditFormat(Local.From)#</cfoutput>
```